# Distribution of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

We have that $X\sim U[0,2]$ and $Y=\min (X,1)$.

I want to find the distribution of $Y$.

We have that \begin{align*}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)=P(\min (X,1)\leq y)=P([X\leq y] \text{ or } \ [1\leq y])=P(\{X\leq y\}\cup \{1\leq y\})\\ & =P(X\leq y)+P(1\leq y)\end{align*}

Is everything correct so far?

Since $X\sim U[0,2]$ do we have that $P(X\leq y)=y$ ? What does it hold for $P(1\leq y)$ ?

$$$$

Coul you give me also a hint how we could calculate the expected value of $Y$ ?

Comment: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ under the extra condition that $P(A\cap B)=0$. Can you say that of the events $A=\{X\leq y\}$ and $B=\{1\leq y\}$? Secondly if indeed $P(X\leq y)=y$ then $P(X\leq 1.5)=1.5>1$. Thirdly: a constant $c$ can be looked at as a random variable. This with $P(c\in A)=1_A(c)$ for every Borelset $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P\big(\{X\le y\}\cup\{1\le y\}\big)$ need not be equal to $P(X\le y)+P(1\le y)$, unless the two events are disjoint.  We have
$$P(X\le y)=\begin{cases}0,&y<0\\\frac{y}{2},&0\le y< 2\\1,&2\le y\end{cases}$$
Also trivially, we have
$$P(1\le y)=\begin{cases}0,&y<1\\1,&y\ge 1\end{cases}$$
Then we have $\{X\le y\}\cap\{1\le y\}=\begin{cases}\emptyset,&y<1\\\{X\le y\},&y\ge 1\end{cases}$

So $$F_Y(y)=P\big(\{X\le y\}\cup\{1\le y\}\big)=P(X\le y)+P(1\le y)-P\big(\{X\le y\}\cap\{1\le y\}\big)=\begin{cases}P(X\le y)+P(1\le y)=\frac{y}{2},&y<1\\P(1\le y)=1,&y\ge 1\end{cases}$$

Thus $F_Y$ has a jump discontinuity at $y=1$ and we get $$P(Y=1)=P(Y\le 1)-P(Y<1)=F_Y(1)-\lim_{y\to 1,\,y<1}F_Y(y)=1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

We also have $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2},\,y<1$. So $$E[Y]=\int_0^1yf_Y(y)dy+1\cdot P(Y=1)=\int_0^1\frac{y}{2}dy+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: We get the three cases of $P(X\leq y)$ by the definition that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$, right? Then at $P(1\leq y)$ if $y<1$ then we have a non-true inequality so the probability is equal to $0$ and if $y\geq 1$ the inequality is true and so the probability is equal to $1$. Is this correct? For the intersection $\{X\le y\}\cap\{1\le y\}$ we have that if $y<1$ then $\{1\le y\}$ is the empty set, and so the intersection becomes also the empty set. If $y\geq 1$ then $\{1\le y\}$ is alwaus true and so the intersection is equal to $\{X\le y\}$, right?

Comment: Why do we have to add at $E[Y]$ the term $1\cdot P(Y=1)$ ? Do we not have the following? \begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[Y]&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)dx \\ & =\int_{-\infty}^{0}yf_Y(y)dx+\int_{0}^{1}yf_Y(y)dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)dx \\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{0}y\cdot 0 \ dx+\int_{0}^{1}y\cdot \frac{1}{2} \ dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}y\cdot 0 \ dx\\ & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{1}y \ dx  = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}\end{align*}

Comment: That's because the integral of $f_Y$ accounts only for the probabilities contributed by the points of continuity of $F_Y$.  The jump discontinuity at 1 contributes separately to the total probability.  That is why $P(X<1)\ne P(X\le 1)$, since we have a jump at 1 and hence $P(X=1)>0$.   Very formally speaking, $F_Y$ is the sum of a continuous 'part' and a discrete 'part'.  It is for this reason that the random variable $Y$ in this case is neither discrete nor continuous, it is mixed.  And your description in the earlier comment is perfectly correct.

Comment: So, do we not use in this case the formula $$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yf_Y(y)dx$$ ?

Comment: Correct, it is the integral plus the 'weight' at the jump 1.

Comment: Ah ok! I understand! How could we calculate $E[Y^2]$ ?

Comment: Similarly.... Now it will be the integral of $y^2f_Y(y)$ plus the weight $1^2\cdot P(X=1)$.

Comment: So, we have that \begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[Y^2]&=\int_{-\infty}^{1}y^2f_Y(y)dx+1^2\cdot P(Y=1)+\int_{1}^{\infty}y^2f_Y(y)dx \\ & =\int_{-\infty}^{0}y^2f_Y(y)dx+\int_{0}^{1}y^2f_Y(y)dx+1\cdot P(Y=1)+\int_{1}^{\infty}y^2f_Y(y)dx \\ & = \int_{-\infty}^{0}y^2\cdot 0 \ dx+\int_{0}^{1}y^2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \ dx+  P(Y=1)+\int_{1}^{\infty}y^2\cdot 0 \ dx \\ & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \int_{0}^{1}y^2 \ dx +  P(Y=1)\\ & = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{2}= \frac{2}{3}\end{align*} right?

Comment: Yes... exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we just have
$$f_Y(y)=\frac12$$
for $y<1$, and
$P(Y=1)=\frac12$.

Hence,
$$E[Y]=\int_0^1\frac{y}{2} \ dy +1\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for finding CDF:

$$\begin{aligned}1-F_{Y}\left(y\right) & =\mathsf{P}\left(\min\left(X,1\right)>y\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{P}\left(X>y\wedge1>y\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{P}\left(X>y\right)\mathsf{P}\left(1>y\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{P}\left(X>y\right)1_{\left(y,\infty\right)}\left(1\right)\\
 & =\mathsf{P}\left(X>y\right)1_{\left(-\infty,1\right)}\left(y\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $1$ is treated as a constant random variable.

The third equality because a constant random variable is independent wrt to any random variable.